# Block keyboard input chatbot

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, chatbot

I am building a ChatBot using C# and Visual Studio. What I want to do is after some queries to the ChatBot, the user can't use the keyboard anymore, I've seen some websites that explain how to do it but I didn't understand well, so if someone can help me.

The idea is to put in the else block something that prevent the user to write to the ChatBot, so if he want to write the things that he type won't appear on the screen. Here is my code :

```
private int NombreDeMessages;
protected override async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
{
    var message = await item;
    NombreDeMessages += 1;
    string code = EndOfConversationCodes.CompletedSuccessfully;
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken);


    if (message.Text != null && NombreDeMessages < 3)
    {
        await base.MessageReceived(context, item);
    }
    else if (message.Text != null && NombreDeMessages == 3)
    {
        AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard();
        card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = "STOP FLOODING",
            Weight = TextWeight.Bolder,
            IsSubtle = true,
            Wrap = true,
            Size = TextSize.Large
        });

        card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = "You have reach the limit of queries",
            IsSubtle = false,
            Wrap = true,
            Size = TextSize.Normal
        });

        card.Body.Add(new Image()
        {
            Url = "http://images.roadtrafficsigns.com/img/dp/lg/traffic-stop-sign.png",

            HorizontalAlignment = AdaptiveCards.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            Size = ImageSize.Stretch
        });

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
            Content = card
        };
        var flood = context.MakeMessage();
        flood.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        await context.PostAsync(flood);
    }
    else
    {
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();

        reply.Type = ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation;
        reply.AsEndOfConversationActivity().Code = code;

        await context.PostAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

---

Yes I want to block input on the web application, I don't have a C# application. My HTML code is this one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <script>
(function () {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
        div.outerHTML = "<div id='botDiv' style='height: 38px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; z-index: 1000; background-color: #fff'><div id='botTitleBar' style='height: 38px; width: 400px; position:fixed; cursor: pointer;'></div><iframe width='400' height='600' src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/supportbotv2?s=4mHD9MekOvU.cwA.8ZU.Pn31pCpv8kyq7UQCr3y4bM-99W4eHxUt-LlhBnCp9JY'></iframe></div>";

        document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.target.matches = e.target.matches || e.target.msMatchesSelector;
            if (e.target.matches('#botTitleBar')) {
                var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv');
                botDiv.style.height = botDiv.style.height == '600px' ? '38px' : '600px';
            };
        });
    }());</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with disabling the control where keyboard input is taken? For example:

```
this.textBox1.enabled = false
```

Comment: The problem is that the ChatBot is embedded in a website with an iframe link so I think I can't reach the textbox where keyboard input is taken. And to test my code and my ChatBot I'm using Bot Framework Channel Emulator. So I think it won't work

Comment: So you want to block input on the web application or do you have a c# (winforms) application?

Comment: Yes I want to block input on the web application, I don't have a c# application. You can see my HTML code in my question.